# How does the linear inequalities concept work?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

A question:
$\frac{1}{x}> 4$.   We can interchange the places of  $x$ and $4$ by multiplication and division of the same. We get:
$$x<\frac{1}{4}$$ 
Let,x be $\frac{1}{10}$. So the equation solves into:
$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}}>4$ which implies $10>4$. This solution is true.

But when, $\frac{1}{x}>-4$    we can interchange places of $x$ and $4$. Since $4$ is negative, we have to change sign of inequality too.
The equation becomes :
$\frac{-1}{4}<x$
if we put $\frac{-1}{10}$ as $x$,we get:
$\frac{1}{\frac{-1}{10}}>-4$ which gives: $-10> -4$ which is not correct.
How does the above happen?

Comment: There is no "picture" to refer to, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the inequality

$$\frac{1}{x}>-4$$

you may indeed divide by $-4$, giving

$$-\frac{1}{4x}<1$$

But you're wrong to say you can "interchange the places" of $x$ and $-4$. You cannot multiply by $x$ *unless you make an assumption about its sign*, for otherwise you don't know what to do with the inequality sign. So you may break your work into two cases:

- **Case One:** $x>0$

Then multiplication by $x$ gives $-\frac{1}{4}<x$. But to deduce this inequality we had to assume $x>0$ anyway. So we conclude $x>0$.

- **Case Two:** $x<0$

Now multiplication by $x$ gives $-\frac{1}{4}>x$. This is consistent with the assumption $x<0$, so we conclude $x<-\frac{1}{4}$.

---

Therefore the solution to $\frac{1}{x}>-4$ is that *either* $x>0$ *or* $x<-\frac{1}{4}$.

The moral of this example is that you cannot multiply or divide by a variable in an inequality unless you know its sign. In particular, you cannot think of a proportional inequality $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{c}{d}$ as if it were a proportional equation $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$, where $a$ and $d$ can trade places -- *unless* you have information about the signs of $a$ and $d$.

Answer (score 1):

In an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) only multiplication by positive numbers will respect the sign. Multiplication by a negative number will reverse the sign. As you can see ignoring this leads to problems immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, I think, it's the following.
$$\frac{1}{x}-4>0$$ or
$$\frac{1-4x}{x}>0$$ or
$$0<x<\frac{1}{4}.$$
Done!